# Is "$\cdot$" associative on R\Q?

Tags: group-theory

If (G,$\ast$) be a group and H be a subset of G which is not closed under$\ast$.So can we say by hereditary property H is closed under $\ast$.
I am reading a group theory text where I found that {Set of positive Irrationals }U{1} is associative ,have a identity,every element have inverse under multiplication but due to failure of closure property it's not a group.But my question is if the set is not closed then how can associative property holds. Can we say (sqrt(2)$\cdot$sqrt(2))$\cdot$sqrt(3) and sqrt(2)$\cdot$(sqrt(2)$\cdot$sqrt(3)) are same.
According to me they are not same as the first one doesn't exists as the operation is restricted on Irrationals.
If we consider the group (R,$\ast$)($\ast$is multiplication operation) then $\ast$ is associative on R\Q,but the restriction mapping is not associative.
So 1)Associative property does not hold if $\cdot$ is defined on R\Q×R\Q
      2)Associative property holds if $\ast$ is defined on R but for the restricted map$\ast$/R-Q associative property fails.
 Am I true or there is any logical flaw.Please help.

Comment: Normally associativity is a property of a binary operation, which by definition is closed.

Comment: If you put asterisks around text, it italicizes the text instead of showing a couple asterisks. You should instead use $\LaTeX$ and type `$\ast$` which will show up as $\ast$. So then you can put asterisks around text..., $\ast$like this$\ast$. Now you can fix your post. You can also use `$\cdot$` for a $\cdot$ symbol

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'd disagree with the book.

I'd say for $a = \sqrt 2; b = \sqrt 2; c = \sqrt 3$ then $a*(b*c) = 2\sqrt 3$ but $(a*b)*c$ is undefined as $(a*b)$ is neither irrational nor $1$.

However, I suppose the book is thinking, $*$ is defined not merely in $H$ but in a larger $G$.   In which case $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$ so it is associative.... *over* $G$.

I'd say it's semantic. But I agree with you,  if we are talking about $*$ being associative *while* talking about a set $H$, I would *assume* we are talking about $*$ being associative *over* $H$.  Which is absolutely is not.

.... so the book isn't *wrong* but... I'd say it could be argued.

Comment: So if (R\Q,$\cdot$) is given then whether I have to consider (R,$\cdot$) for associativity or not